# When comparing in if statements in PHP, would it be case sensitive?

Tags: php, html

If I had a code like, `if ($_REQUEST['carrier'] == "T-Mobile") {}` could I not have to do `"t-mobile"` as well if someone for example, forgets to capitalize they're carrier name? I am writing an email text subscription system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the strcasecmp function to check if the two strings are equal (case insensitive).

If they are equal, this function returns 0.

Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

Your if would look like this

```
if (strcasecmp($_REQUEST['carrier'], "T-Mobile") == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant' really figure out your question but...

Try to convert both to lower case and compare thusly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's case sensitive. The solution is to convert the input to lowercase:

```
if (strtolower($_REQUEST['carrier']) == "t-mobile") {
```

Comment: Thank you for you're suguestion. I will keep that in mind when I'm writing the rest of this script.

Answer (score 0):

[strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
if (strtolower($_REQUEST['carrier']) == "t-mobile") { /* ... */ }
```

There are more elegant ways to do it, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for you're suguestion. I will keep that in mind when I'm writing the rest of this script.